# Problems with dynamic select boxes

Tags: jquery

my application has a table with one row and a "Add" button for add more lines using the jquery's clone method. Each of these lines has two select boxes that are filled dynamically using jquery.

The IDs of select boxes are dinamically generated (mark1, mark2, mark3, ...) and (model1, model2, model3, ...).

I use a for loop to fill all the select boxes but this is not working. Here is my code:

```
for(count=1; count<=numRows; count++) { 

    $('#mark'+count).change(function(){

        $('#model'+count).load('findModel.php?mark='+$('#mark'+count).val());

    });

}
```

Is it possible with jquery?

Thanks,
Marcelo.

Hi Simdrouin, I'm using another script (countRows.php) to receive the number of rows and pass it again to the main script.

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'countRows.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { data : window.numRows },
    success: function (data) {

    $('#mark'+data).change(function(){

        $('#model'+data).load('findModel.php?mark='+$('#mark'+data).val()+'&numRows='+window.numRows);

    });

});
```

countRows.php

```
<?

$numRows=$_POST['data'];
echo $numRows;

?>
```

Thanks,
Marcelo.

Comment: Did you made it work ?  Did my anwser help?

Comment: Hi Simdrouin, I'm using another script (countRows.php) to receive the number of rows and pass it again to the main script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the *count* variable inside the change event.

Here is a jsfiddle that's not exactly your case with the PHP file, but might give you some ideas:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ex9pu/

I added a data-id attribute to the markX select for further reference :

```
$('#mark' + (i+1)).data('index', i);
```

Then in the change event, you can reference it to get the corresponding models:

```
var index = $(this).data('index');
```

Note that since I did not have access to your php files, I appended the content from arrays.